# Merging two objects in node

Tags: node.js, typescript

This is my structure

```
 [{
"date": "2019-01-10T18:30:00.000Z",
"time": "2019-01-11T04:37:49.587Z",
"abc_Info": {
  "_id": "5c381da651f18d5040611eb2",
  "abc": 2.5,
  "guardian": "XYZ"
  }
}]
```

What I want is

```
[{
"date": "2019-01-10T18:30:00.000Z",
"time": "2019-01-11T04:37:49.587Z",
"abc": 2.5,
"guardian": "XYZ"
}]
```

**Code**

```
this._model.find(params, (err, docs) => {
  if (err) {
    var response = this.errorResponse("error", 500, null);
    res.send(response);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
      const abc= {
        "date": docs[i].date,
        "time": docs[i].time,
      "abc_Info":docs[i].abc_Info //this is object, i couldn't select value separately from this object
      }
      if (docs[i].abc_Info != undefined) {
        abcArray.push(abc);
      }
    }
    res.send(abc);
  }
});
```

I am trying to select values from object like **"abc_Info":docs[i].abc_Info.abc** but I couldn't do it, Its throwing error.
There are two way I can achieve this.

1. Selecting values directly from object and store in variable. That is throwing error for me
2. Merging date and time with abc_Info. I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Chnage this.

```
const abc= {
    "date": docs[i].date,
    "time": docs[i].time,
    "abc":docs[i].abc_Info.abc,
    "guardian":docs[i].abc_Info.guardian
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hope it will be helpful

```js
var d=[{
"date": "2019-01-10T18:30:00.000Z",
"time": "2019-01-11T04:37:49.587Z",
"abc_Info": {
  "_id": "5c381da651f18d5040611eb2",
  "abc": 2.5,
  "guardian": "XYZ"
  }
}]

d[0]=Object.assign(d[0],d[0].abc_Info);
delete d[0]['abc_Info'];
delete d[0]['_id'];
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let x = {

      "date": "2019-01-10T18:30:00.000Z",
      "time": "2019-01-11T04:37:49.587Z",
}
let abc_Info = {
      "_id": "5c381da651f18d5040611eb2",
      "abc": 2.5,
      "guardian": "XYZ"
}
// to concat 
let z = {...x, ...abc_Info}
console.log(z)
```

You can use the above `ES6 spread operator` for the cause
`Object.assign` is quite better in performance so it'll be like this:
Or `let z = Object.assign(x, abc_info);`

**In your code it should be like this:**

```
const abc= {...{
        "date": docs[i].date,
        "time": docs[i].time,
      }, ...docs[i].abc_Info}
```

Comment: I am getting meta data as my response like  "$parent"

Answer (score 0):

Use Spread operator and also rather using for loop and push, use Array.prototype.map

```js
let docs= [{
"date": "2019-01-10T18:30:00.000Z",
"time": "2019-01-11T04:37:49.587Z",
"abc_Info": {
  "_id": "5c381da651f18d5040611eb2",
  "abc": 2.5,
  "guardian": "XYZ"
  }
}]

let abcArray = docs.map(({date, time, abc_Info}) => {
  delete abc_Info._id;
  return {date, time, ...abc_Info }
});

console.log(abcArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry Its my mistake. I should have declared object inside if statement. Its working now

```
      if (docs[i].abc_Info != undefined) {
      const abc= {
        "date": docs[i].date,
        "time": docs[i].time,
       "abc_Info":docs[i].abc_Info
        }
        abcArray.push(abc);
      }
```